# One Large MySQL Table Vs 20 - 50 Smaller Tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am starting a project where the performance(Speed) of each result from the queries are very important.

The Situation:

- Around 20-50 Products (Will increase over time: about 3/year)
- Each Product has a Profile page with around 20 VARs that requires to be store
- Each Product has a pricing that will be change(Insert/Add) **---Daily---**
- Each Product will also have a VAR for a monthly, 3month, 6month, 1year, 3year Price, updated randomly
- Output 1 (Est. 5,000 Views Daily)

All Products, Current Day Pricing, Price Difference, Percentage Difference, Pervious Price

- Output 2 (Form search by range for **Individual** Product | views unknown Est. 100 views Daily)

Date, Price, Price Difference, Percentage Difference, Pervious Price

- Addictions. Random put of pricing will be required.

Note: This Project is build on ExpressionEngine

**My Main Question is whether I should make a table that keeps all the product information with a product ID and then have all the daily pricing for all the products in one table. Then all the monthly pricing for all product in the second table etc. for the different pricing since each type of pricing will only be use a type at a time.**

**Or. Should I make 20-30 tables that stores their own daily pricing? then use JOIN when querying**

I have looked into a lot of similar questions and answer but I can't seem to find a close enough situation.

Comment: It's impossible to answer to your question. Neither answer is correct for such vague explanation. But the thing is - as long as you ask such questions, then there is a chance that how many tables to use is the less thing you should care about now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output 1.  Any time you do a full table scan to return all rows from the data base it can become time consuming.  However 20-50 products is chump change and the database should not have a problem.  If you begin to add a lot of products you can always introduce pagination and display 100 or so products per page.  A second approach is to just cache the home page for a set amount of time and refresh it periodically.

Output 2.  As long as you have product Ids or titles indexed individual product look ups should be very quick.

20-30 tables sounds like hell to maintain and doing that many joins would be a nightmare.  Don't try to optimize prematurely.  Only focus on it when you identify a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helps to ease my stress over deciding on which way to go.

Comment: I dont have any experience with ExpressionEngine but I use mysql at work with databases that get 400,000 rows a day and only very complicated queries are slow.  If I only return a few hundred or thousand rows its quick.

Answer (score 0):

I will always lean towards the single table approach rather than a set of tables.

You should use indexing on the table, which will greatly improve performance.

The overhead to maitain your own rolled table partitioning far outweighs the single table approach.

You should have a single table per "entity".

So a table for product static data, a table for pricing data, etc..

Answer (score 0):

adopt a parent child method. and identify the proper relationships of your tables. also the handling of your data will depend on what software you will used in your backend..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not entirely clear what you're asking - are you asking whether you should denormalize your data, or whether you should partition your data?

Secondly, the answer to both questions is "no". Or, more accurately "No, please, please no, in the name of all that is holy - NO!".

Your database is going to be tiny - 50 products with 365 price changes per year is still only 15K records. You're not even close to the point where a decently designed "traditional" database schema would be slow; both denormalization and partitioning create major maintenance overhead, make the application more brittle, and involve significant amounts of development time.

I'd strongly recommend building a normalized data model, populating it with lots of data (at least double your anticipated maximum), run the queries you expect to run, and then work out whether you even have a problem by measuring the performance of the queries. If you do, optimize the queries. If it's still to slow, buy bigger/better hardware. If it's still to slow, consider de-normalizing. If that's too slow, you're working for Facebook.